# Contracting like elements over python lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a list of names, say

```
m=['l','l','k','j','h','k']
```

and also an array of values corresponding to them:

```
n = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,1,2,3]])
```

I would like to contract m so as to include only the unique elements (which I can do using np.unique) but also then ADD the corresponding elements of the two rows in array n.

How should I do this efficiently? At present, I can only think of iterating over the elements of m to find all other elements in m that are the same, and then contracting these columns of n. Very inefficient!

EDIT:

expected ouptu:

```
m=array(['h', 'j', 'k', 'l'], dtype='<U1')

n=np.array([[5,4,9,3],[2,1,12,15]])
```

Comment: What do you mean by _contract_?

Comment: @Chris 'contract m so as to include only the unique elements'

Comment: And what about the _corresponding elements_? based on the removed elements' indices in `m`? I still don't see your logic of getting the expected output :(

Comment: The array m has 6 names/labels originally. The array n is 2x6, with each row corresponding to a property of the label, each ith column in n corresponding to the ith label in m. I need to add the occurances of the same event for each record of the same label. @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication with a sparse matrix for efficiency:

```
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                   
from scipy import sparse

m=['l','l','k','j','h','k']
n = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,1,2,3]])

unq, idx = np.unique(m, return_inverse=True)
res = n@sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(idx),idx,np.arange(idx.size+1)))

unq
# array(['h', 'j', 'k', 'l'], dtype='<U1')
res
# array([[ 5,  4,  9,  3],
#        [ 2,  1, 12, 15]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the flag `return_index` of `np.unique` to `True`

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.array(['l','l','k','j','h','k'])
n = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,1,2,3]])    


unique_elements, unique_indices = np.unique(m, return_index=True)

# you can return the unique elements as well as the corresponding indices        
print(unique_elements, unique_indices)        


# so you get what you want with:
print(m[unique_indices])
print(n[:,unique_indices])
```